How to prove this peculiar relationship between minimal polynomials of Ramanujan class invariants?
The Ramanujan class invariants (a.k.a. "Ramanujan-Weber class invariants")
are defined for $n>0$ by
$$G_n=2^{-1/4}e^{\pi\sqrt{n}/24}\prod_{k=0}^\infty \left(1+e^{-(2k+1)\pi\sqrt{n}}\right),$$ $$g_n=2^{-1/4}e^{\pi\sqrt{n}/24}\prod_{k=0}^\infty \left(1-e^{-(2k+1)\pi\sqrt{n}}\right).$$ It is well known that they are algebraic whenever $n\in\mathbb Q$ and closely related to the elliptic modulus $\lambda^*(n)=k_n$. For $r\in\mathbb Q^+$, let's denote by $M_r(x)$ and $m_r(x)$ respectively the minimal polynomial of $G_r$ and $g_r$.
There are a bunch of papers where modular equations are used to obtain beautiful expressions for certain $G_r$ and $g_r$, usually in nested radicals. But surprisingly, I have hardly found anything about their minimal polynomials as such.
Using the algdep() function in PARI, I have calculated (modulo a disclaimer analogous to the last paragraph here) about half of them for all $1\leqslant p,q\leqslant 100$. While their degrees are about as unpredictable as e.g. the coefficients of the Ramanujan tau function, there seem to be, for a given $r=\frac pq$, relations between the degrees of $M_r$ and $m_r$. BTW I have a full conjecture about the quotient of the degrees $d_r:=\dfrac{\partial   M_r}{\partial   m_r}$, which in all my data is always one of  $\{ \dfrac{1}{16},\dfrac{1}{8}, \dfrac{1}{4},1,2,8,16\}$ depending only on $p,q \pmod 8$. (Of course, $p$ and $q$ are always meant to be coprime.)
But the question I want to ask here, as an 'appetizer,' is just about the case $d_r=1$. This case seems to occur iff $r=\frac pq$ with odd $p$ and even $q$, and moreover those $M_r(x)$ and $m_r(x)$ have always the same coefficients up to sign. More precisely: it is all the signs of odd powers of $x^8$ that differ (noting that all minimal polynomials for those $r$ appear to be polynomials in $x^8$ - see (*) below). So we have e.g.
$$M_{1/10}=
16x^{32} - 112x^{24} - 12x^{16} + 188x^8 + 1,
$$
$$m_{1/10}=16x^{32} + 112x^{24} - 12x^{16} - 188x^8 + 1.$$
Thus so to speak, the sign change in the definition of $G_r$ vs. $g_r$ goes for those $r$ along with a sign change in every other coefficient. (And also, if ever these $G_r$ and $g_r$ can be expressed in radicals, supposedly they can be written in a way that the only difference should be some signs before square roots.) In a certain sense, those two polynomials are 'conjugate' to each other. In fact, if $\zeta_{16}$ denotes a primitive $16$th root of unity, we have $\zeta_{16}^8=-1$, so given the fact that those are minimal polynomials, the statement can be formulated equivalently as follows:

Conjecture: For $n=\frac pq$ with odd $p$ and even $q$ and any polynomial $f$ with rational coefficients, we should have $$f(G_n)=0\Longleftrightarrow f(\zeta_{16} g_n)=0$$$$ \text{ and }$$$$f(g_n)=0\Longleftrightarrow f(\zeta_{16} G_n)=0.$$

Note that this has a priori nothing to do with the well-known identity valid for all (real) $n>0$ $$ (g_nG_n)^8(G_n^8-g_n^8)=\frac14.$$
Any idea how to prove this conjecture?
Note: I have posted this last week on MO but got no reply so far. I know that often the order of posting is the other way round, but I figured that this conjecture seems to be deeper than it looks at first glance and moreover, brand new. So I deemed that MO might be the better place to post it. But I now see that the keyword "Ramanujan class invariant" is a bit more frequent here on math.SE, so hopefully someone here can share their insights.

 (*) BTW among other conjectures, I also have a full conjecture about what I'd call the granularity (i.e. the biggest power $k$ such that it's actually a polynomial in $x^k$, thus $8$ in the above case). The granularity seems to be always a divisor of $24$, depending only on $p,q \pmod {24}$ for $M_{p/q}$ and on  $p,q \pmod {12}$ for $m_{p/q}$. Knowing the granularity to expect has helped in turn tremendously accelerating the search for the minimal polynomials as $p$ and $q$ get bigger.

